# Trying to figure out fuse specs ("3/2 3AG 1A 250V")

Tags: fuses

I need to replace a fuse, and I'm trying to get my arms around the specs.  The fuse is stamped "3/2 3AG", then "1A 250V".

What does the 3/2 signify?  Is that related to how fast the fuse is?

Does "3AG" mean the same thing as "AGC"?  Or can I mostly ignore it and just look for fuses that are 1/4 by 1-1/4 inches?

The only other markings are the manufacturer's name (LittelFuse USA) and logo.

What do I need to look for here to replace this safely?

Answer (score 1):

Probably 312 is the series number. In which case, [this](https://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/fuses/littelfuse_fuse_312_318_datasheet.pdf.pdf) would be the appropriate datasheet, and the Littelfuse part number would be 0312001-?XP where ? is packaging-dependent.